# Geocoder throwing exception: Service is not available in Android (Google api) 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-maps, android-location

I am using GeoCoder for getting the location in my application. The following code is:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
try {
   List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("", 1);
   if(null != addresses && addresses.size() > 0){
       address = addresses.get(0);
       List<Overlay> mapOverlay = mapView.getOverlays();
           //This is new class to get address on basis on latitude and longitude
       AddressOverlay addressOverlay = new AddressOverlay(address);
       mapOverlay.add(addressOverlay);
       final MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

           //Start animating the map towards the given point.
       mapController.animateTo(addressOverlay.getGeoPoint(), new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
             mapController.setZoom(12);
          }
       });
    }else{
      //No results for that address.
 }
```

I am getting exception: Service is not available on 1st line (just after try). Is there any person who can mentor to me and provide the steps to resolve this problem?

wait for prompt response!!